# Laravel API Security

Tags: api, security, laravel

I'm writing my first Laravel API as a project to get to know Laravel. Also, I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I hope my question is correct. I made the API but now all users over the world can use all methods(`GET`, `POST` etc).

My question is how to block these users and allow all methods only for the app, maybe host's ip or something else?

Comment: There are many ways of acheiving that. Which users do you want to access your API? Do you want to implement authentication?

Comment: @raviolicode When i write in browser .../api/comments it will show me the comments, but i want to remove it and nobody have access for the api's 'route::group'. Only when my app needs for this api, it has rights.

Comment: And i use it for AngularJS. Maybe that's important.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @michael I use this API for AngularJS's app. The AngularJS's app and the Laravel framework are on the same server. The index.php file of AngularJS'app is on the Laravel's view. I want to make only this index.php(view) has access for the API, nobody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need authentication. If you want to to protect a specific group, try adding a HTTP Middleware. There are several middleware included in the Laravel framework, including middleware for maintenance, authentication, CSRF protection, and more. All of these middleware are located in the `app/Http/Middleware` directory.

For instance if you want to protect a whole route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

Try reading about [middlewares](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) and [authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) from the laravel docs. They are nicely written.

Comment: OK. I saw laravel docs for middlewares and authenrication. But is it correct  to write in the route: 
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', function ()    {
        
    });
});

when i have this also and in the AngularJS routes?

Comment: @user3084507 You need to understand that these are the server side routes. Angular routes will not be affected with what you do on the server side.